# How to implement google ML kit for detecting head movement of a person by front and rear camera simultaneously

Tags: android, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I have implemented google ML Kit for detecting head movement of a person by front camera it is working fine but when I use both camera simultaneously it is not working fine the last initialized camera override the first one how to resolve this issue ?

I want to implement google ML Kit on both camera simultaneously to detect human head movement

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think this question is less relevant with ML Kit API, but more relevant with how to open two cameras at the same time.